# how can I get dbt macro to return a table

Tags: dbt

I tried to use macro to create a temp table for my snapshot to be taken on. However, the macro returns nothing.
Here is my macro code:

```
{% macro notifications_clean() %}
{% if execute %}

    {% set nc_sql %}
        
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_notifications AS
        {% if var('full_load') == true %}

            {{ log('Dropping existing snapshot for conforming_notifications.notifications and derived current table for notifications_current', info=True) }}
            {% set dropsnapshot %}
                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS conforming_notifications.notifications CASCADE;
            {% endset %}
            {% do run_query(dropsnapshot) %}

            {{ log('Getting all data after last full load operation', info=True) }}

            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                raw_notifications.dbo_notifications
            WHERE
                etl_loaddate >= cast ((select max(etl_loaddate) from raw_notifications.dbo_notifications WHERE op = 'H') as date)

        {% else %}
        
            {{ log('Getting all cdc data after last snapshot operation', info=True) }}

            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                raw_notifications.dbo_notifications
            WHERE
                cdcoperationtimestamp >= (SELECT MAX(etl_loaddate) max_etl_loaddate FROM raw_notifications.dbo_notifications WHERE op = 'H')

        {% endif %}

    {% endset %}
    
   -- {% do run_query(nc_sql) %}
    {{ return(temp_notifications) }}

{% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

Below is my snapshot which is based on the macro:

```
{% snapshot notifications %}

    {{
        config(
            target_database='dwh',
            target_schema='conforming_notifications',
            strategy='timestamp',
            unique_key='id',
            updated_at='cdcoperationtimestamp'
        )
    }}



    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        {{ notifications_clean() }}

{% endsnapshot %}
```

While the error message received is

```bash
00:45:38  Database Error in snapshot notifications (snapshots/conforming_notifications.sql)
00:45:38    syntax error at or near ")"
00:45:38    LINE 32:     ) sbq
00:45:38                 ^
00:45:38    compiled SQL at target/run/data_platform/snapshots/conforming_notifications.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

welcome to dbt and SO.

There are a few things going on here:

1. Temp tables are a bit of an antipattern in dbt. Your temp table should probably just be an ordinary table, which means it should probably be a dbt model, not a macro. (dbt uses multiple sessions/connections to your data warehouse, and since your temp table will get dropped when the session ends, there is no guarantee it will be available for dbt to query)
2. DDL is also an antipattern in dbt. The whole point of dbt is that it writes the DDL for you. You just write something that looks like a select statement and it does the rest
3. If you're *going* to use DDL in dbt macros, etc., (like dropping a table with a macro), you need to manually manage transactions yourself, and issue a `COMMIT;` command. Otherwise your DDL is likely to be rolled back
4. You should think of jinja macros as operating on text files on your machine, not operating on the remote database. While you *can* use the `{{ run_query() }}` macro, that macro is usually intended to just fetch a few values from the database for help in templating a larger query. You don't really want to use a macro to issue instructions to the db in most cases (see #2, above). Accordingly, you don't really want your macro to **return** a query -- you want your macro to write the SQL that can be executed for that query.

With that out of the way, I wouldn't use a macro for your use case, at all. In fact, I think a vanilla snapshot of your table would work great:

```sql
{% snapshot notifications %}

    {{
        config(
            target_database='dwh',
            target_schema='conforming_notifications',
            strategy='timestamp',
            unique_key='id',
            updated_at='cdcoperationtimestamp'
        )
    }}

    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        raw_notifications.dbo_notifications
        -- or ideally {{ source('raw_notifications', 'dbo_notifications') }}

{% endsnapshot %}
```

Part of the snapshot's job is to introspect the existing snapshot and only append the new/updated records. With a `timestamp` strategy, this should be very efficient and performant (and no different than the filtering you're doing in the macro) -- if it's not, then add a sort/partition/clustering to your source table. And unlike other dbt-managed data assets, snapshots should really be treated like source data, and not dropped regularly.